# Filtering list, getting no results. Code and more details inside

Tags: django, list, django-queryset

First I get the articles in the category with articles_in_cat (works), then I try and get the HitCount objects that represent those articles, with articles_hit. articles_hit doesn't throw any errors, but it's an empty list. Any idea what the problem is?

```
def cat_home(request, id):
    n = categories.objects.get(id = id)
    articles_in_cat = list(article.objects.filter(category = n))
    articles_hit = list(HitCount.objects.filter(object_pk = articles_in_cat).order_by('hits')
```

Comment: try  `articles_hit = list(HitCount.objects.filter(object_pk__in = articles_in_cat).order_by('hits')`

Comment: Please post your models.py

Comment: Im referencing [the HitCount model here](https://github.com/kevinpostal/Art-Acclaim/blob/master/hitcount/models.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's try again:

```
n = categories.objects.get(id = id) #  you say it works

# you wrote 'article' but model's name should be Article
articles_titles_in_cat [a.title for a in article.objects.filter(category = n)] 
# it should give you articles' title which match category n

#and then
articles_hit = list(HitCount.objects.filter(object_pk__in = articles_titles_in_cat).order_by('hits'))
#assuming object_pk contains "article's title" as you mentioned in a coment
```

Comment: I've been reading those docs all morning and overlooked that, haha, thanks. Its still returning an empty list though :/

Comment: ok, are you sure you should use `object_pk` instead something like `category_id` ?

Comment: I thought I needed object_pk, but maybe not. Its [the HitCount model here](https://github.com/kevinpostal/Art-Acclaim/blob/master/hitcount/models.py) that I'm referencing.

Comment: where is article model? what is the purpose of hitcount? HitCount does not have a ForeignKey to article model. It looks a bit confused

Comment: HitCount is an app that keeps track of views. Is there anyway I could get a list of article titles instead of article objects, then compare the titles to the object_pk?

Comment: @user3642742 so, your object_pk contains "article titles"? and yes, you can get just the title if you want

Comment: object_pk is the name of the item its representing, so if there was an article with 10 hits with the title "Bush Paints Stuff", the object_pk would be "Bush Paints Stuff" and so would the article.title. I'm trying to match up the articles with their corresponding hit object, so I can sort articles by views, but only if they're in the right category.

Comment: Im trying to get your edit working now, but it's saying "local variable 'article' referenced before assignment". Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: I advise you to use references instead of simply save the title, it could give you headaches later